# On exchanging partitions, do the exchanged records retain in the original partition?

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

Suppose, I have following table,

```
create table SRC_TABLE (
ID NUMBER(2),
NAME VARCHAR(20)
) PARTITION BY LIST (ID)
(
    PARTITION "PART_1" VALUES(1),
    PARTITION "PART_2" VALUES(2)
)
```

Following are the records in SRC_TABLE

```
ID         NAME    
-----  ------- 
1          src1    
1          src11   
1          src111  
2          src2    
2          src22
```

and other staging table,

```
create table STAGE_TABLE (
ID NUMBER(2),
NAME VARCHAR(20)
)
```

Following are the records in STAGE_TABLE:

```
ID     NAME    
-----  ------- 
2      2src22
```

On running the following query,

```
ALTER TABLE "SRC_TABLE" EXCHANGE PARTITION "PART_1" WITH TABLE "STAGE_TABLE" WITHOUT VALIDATION
```

Data of SRC_TABLE BECOMES:

```
ID     NAME    
-----  ------- 
2      2src22  
2      src2    
2      src22
```

So, now the record with name = '2src22'  (which came from stage table as a result of exchange) remain in PART_1  or  PART_2 since based on ID it should come in PART_2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the [`WITHOUT VALIDATION`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#BABHHAHF) clause, you're telling Oracle: "don't check the new records if they satisfy the partition clause, **I have made sure that they all satisfy the partitioning scheme**".

Basically you have introduced corrupted data in your database and you've told Oracle not to perform any check. You've intentionally deactivated the protection, so naturally the records will end up in the wrong partition:

```
SQL> select * from src_table partition (part_1);

 ID NAME
--- ------------------------------------------------------------
  2 2src22
```

I'm sure you'll run into *fun* bugs if you let your data in the wrong partition. Some select may return inconsistent/wrong results. You may also experience unusual error messages.

For instance, a simple partition pruning will give the wrong result (thanks [@Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole)):

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM src_table WHERE ID = 1;

 ID NAME
--- ------------------------------------------------------------
  2 2src22
```

What happens if you actually use validation:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE "SRC_TABLE" EXCHANGE PARTITION "PART_1" WITH TABLE STAGE_TABLE;

ORA-14099: all rows in table do not qualify for specified partition
```

You get a nice error message explaining that you're trying to do something wrong. Don't try to work around error messages by deactivating protections. Correct your data instead.

Comment: `select * from src_table where id = 1` and `... = 2` both give the wrong results, for a start...

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for the example, that's actually even worse than I was suspecting!